# Conditional redirect in React after async redux call

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, redux-saga

I have relatively simple class based component connected do redux-saga. It contains input and button, when user type something and press the button saga method (async one) with that input as argument runs. After some time it returns some data or error. I want to conditionally redirect user after that async call to different page with some data or to an error page.

So far I managed to write saga and visual part of that component but I still struggle with redirect part.

I mean redux call is successful (redux state changes correctly), my question is how can I detect that a redux state changes inside my component and then redirect user. I assume that I have to use some lifecycle method, but in the same time I don’t want to rerender it (after all in both cases, successful call or error, user will be redirected to different page).

Answer (score 2):

Redirect to a page is based on the router library, in case of using `react-router` (version 4), your configuration should contain some files:

history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

in your App.js file (root component), you use created history instead of the default one

```
import history from 'history' // history is a module comes with react-router

<Router history={history}>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={ComponentX} />
      <Route path="/Y" exact component={ComponentY} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

To redirect to another page after completing an action, your action function will look like this one. In my case I use redux-thunk, the general idea is, the redirecting code comes after completing your `callAPI()` asyn function.

```
export const doSomething = values => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const response = await callAPI();
  // Redirecting code
  if (response.error) history.push("/path/to/your/error/page");
  history.push("/path/to/your/showData/page");
};
```

Side note: To redirect (navigate) to a path in your app. If inside a component, you can use `Link` component of `react-router-dom`, but, outside the component code (redirect programmatically) you have to use `history` like above.

In some specific cases, you need to redirect after the component receives new `props` from application state, use `componentDidUpdate` with `history.push` insde to make it work.

Comment: My api call from redux saves it's result inside redux store and then pass it to my component as a props object. My question is how can I redirecty user when that props change. Let's say that prop object look like that before api call:


{loading: fasle, data: null: error: false}


durning call:
{loading true, data: null: error: false}


when call is successful:
{loading false, data: 'dsadad', error: false}

when error occurs:
{loafing: false, data: null, error: true}

Comment: @delthas side note: If you by chance end up calling a history method in a saga, make sure to use the `call`effect. E.g. `yield call([history, 'push'], '/path')`. Calling it directly might lead to some unforeseen issues.

Comment: @delthas: If you want to redirect after the component receives now props, try `componentDidUpdate` life cycle method. But I think my approach fit your need.

Comment: thanks, @dqlgnoleht componentDidUpdate and history.push worked for me.

Comment: @delthas: I will update the answer so, please help to let mine as accepted one, many thanks.